# Cannot connect Hasura graphql with existing Microsoft SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server, graphql, hasura

I am unable to connect hasura with already existing Microsoft SQL Server database. For testing purpose I have used a local Microsoft SQL Server database with:

- server name: `(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB`
- user_name: user
- password: pass

I have used the hasura cloud for connecting the existing database.

This is the database url:

```
Driver={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server};Server=tcp (LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB,1433;Database=tester;Uid=user;Pwd=password;Encrypt=optional
```

Error :

```json
[
    {
        "definition": "Default",
        "message": {
            "exception": {
                "message": "[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired",
                "type": "unsuccessful_return_code"
            }
        },
        "name": "source Default",
        "reason": "Inconsistent object: mssql connection error",
        "type": "source"
    }
]
```

Comment: Umm, how will cloud be able to connect to your local computer?

Comment: I usually test the other way around, local to cloud. But if you really need to you need to DMZ your IP or a dynamic DNS.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to create yourself a docker compose file to test locally see if you can connect to a local DB, then set it to connect to remote DB.

Here is a sample Docker-compose file

```
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgis/postgis:12-master
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
    command: [ "postgres", "-c", "wal_level=logical" ]
    volumes:
      - database-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/

  hasura:
    image: hasura/graphql-engine:v2.30.1-ce.cli-migrations-v3.ubuntu
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    command: /bin/sh -c 'sleep 20; graphql-engine serve'
    restart: always
    environment:
      HASURA_GRAPHQL_DATABASE_URL: postgres://postgres:postgres@postgres:5432/postgres
      HASURA_GRAPHQL_JWT_SECRET: '{
                "type": "HS256",
                "key": "123"
            }'
      HASURA_GRAPHQL_ADMIN_SECRET: XXX

volumes:
  database-data:
```

I know this is using PG but it's pretty much the same process. Then you can change the variable HASURA_GRAPHQL_DATABASE_URL to set your DB credentials and connection

Comment: Yes, it works for me. But I do have a doubt. So how would i use the HASURA_GRAPHQL_DATABASE_URL env variables to work on the production. How to pass the env variables in the production

Comment: Are you using hosted OR Cloud hasura ?

Comment: HASURA_GRAPHQL_DATABASE_URL can be set in the evn-vars in the hasura cloud console on hasura.io. Otherwise if you are hosting it , well simply export the var before starting as I did on this docker file